# Detecting wifi hotspot iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way to detect whether the wifi hotspot is enabled or not in iOS?

I can detect whether any active hotspot connection is available by checking the ip of iphone which is of the format 172.20.10.x or the status bar color and height changes

but simply enabling the hotspot- checking this condition is the prob

was following the code here http://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/ios-detect-personal-hotspot/#respond

can any one help me on this?

Comment: Arun did you find any solution ? [@arun]

Comment: ^ similar question with above

Answer (score 0):

You can get text message if any device is connect to hotspot by using:-

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILabel *subviews12 = [[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"doubleHeightLabel"];
```